# Unable to access Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Duos, and ever since I bought my cell phone, I am unable to access the Google Play Store due to the error message:

> Authentication is required. You need to sign in to your Google Account.

I had signed in my Google account already and have used it on my phone with other apps, like Talk, Gmail and etc. I have tried clearing the account and re-entering it, wiping out all the data and re-building a new account, and other possible solutions, but still my problem is there.

My one possible guess is that it is due to the country I live in. It may be that Google has put some sanctions on my country, Iran.

How can I get Google Play Store to work on my phone?

Comment: I believe you're correct; Google Play is not currently available in Iran. [This help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2843119?ref_topic=2803017) lists the various Google Play services and where they're available.

Comment: Hm, if I read that page correctly, it doesn't say anything about the availibility of *free* (not-paid) app content (and thus access to them via the *Google Play App*) -- or did I miss something?

Comment: [This page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138294?hl=en&ref_topic=2365624) lists the supported locations for downloading free apps.

Comment: It is really complicated, although i am using a proxy i still get the same error, i wish somebody from google play staff could help!